# Change orientation of bar charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

How can the bar charts from the following code be drawn from the y-axis?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.76, transform shape]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{1.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{100}
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*8,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*1)]in {1,...,10}{\draw [black] (.15,\incrmnty*\y) -- +(0:-.3);}
\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {1,...,8}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(90:10);}
\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {0,...,8}{\draw [black] (\incrmntx*\x,.15) -- +(-90:.3) node [below, black] {\aff};}
\draw[blue, ybar, bar width=.4cm, fill=blue] plot coordinates{(1,1.5) (2,2.5) (3,3.5) };
\node[below] at (1,-.1) {x};
\node[below] at (2,-.1) {y};
\node[below] at (3,-.1) {v};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to be

[image]

instead of

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `ybar` to `xbar`, I think you will get mainly what you envisage (I think):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.76, transform shape]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{100}
    \draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*8,0);
    \draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*1)]in {1,...,10}{\draw [black] (.15,\incrmnty*\y) -- +(0:-.3);}
    \foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {1,...,8}{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(90:10);}
    \foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {0,...,8}{\draw [black] (\incrmntx*\x,.15) -- +(-90:.3) node [below, black] {\aff};}
    \draw[blue, xbar, bar width=.4cm, fill=blue] plot coordinates{(1,1.5) (2,2.5) (3,3.5) };
    \node[below] at (1,-.1) {x};
    \node[below] at (2,-.1) {y};
    \node[below] at (3,-.1) {v};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can y labels be added to the bars instead of defining them separately as nodes?

Comment: @Hany Since you already have the values in hand, you can use the `bar` plots of pgfplots with the data-set being supplied. That makes your life more easier. But, yes, it can be added. I will try to add that part as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Raaja's nice answer but also including a pgfplots alternative.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.76, transform shape,%x={(0,1)},y={(1,0)}
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmntx}{1.2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnty}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{100}
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (\incrmntx*8,0);
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,\incrmnty*10);
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \aff using int(\y*1)]in {1,...,8}
{\draw [black] (.15,\incrmnty*\y) -- +(0:-.3);}
\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {1,...,10}
{\draw [black!20!white] (\incrmntx*\x,0) -- +(90:10);}
\foreach \x [evaluate= \x as \aff using int(\inc*\x)]in {0,...,8}
{\draw [black] (\incrmntx*\x,.15) -- +(-90:.3) node [below, black] {\aff};}
\draw[blue, xbar, bar width=.4cm, fill=blue] 
plot coordinates{(1.5,1) (2.5,2) (3.5,3) };
\node[left] at (-.1,1) {x};
\node[left] at (-.1,2) {y};
\node[left] at (-.1,3) {v};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A pgfplots alternative}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xbar,ytick={1,2,3},yticklabels={x,y,v},ytick={1,2,...,8},
 xmajorgrids,
 ymax=8,xmax=800]
  \addplot coordinates{(150,1) (250,2) (350,3) };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmotThank you for your answer. But how to adjust the alternative method to look like your original code, regarding the axes ticks, and bar spacings.

Comment: @Hany This is rather easy. All you need to do is to add is `ytick={1,2,3},ytick={1,2,...,8},
 xmajorgrids,
 ymax=8,xmax=800` to the axis options. I updated the answer accordingly.